# Can a Spectral Weapon take damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, damage

During a session, we ran across a scenario whereby one of the player's weapons (a Javelin) would do a sort of lightning strike through several squares - including the one my spectral weapon (from the *[Spiritual Weapon](http://ephe.github.io/grimoire/spells/spiritual-weapon)* spell) was on.

Is it possible for spectral weapons to take damage in any situation?  And if so, what situations (and can it make saves?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Spell does not provide a mechanism for doing damage to the spiritual weapon, the mechanics by which it would save, or its susceptibility.

Since nothing is defined, Rules as Written, nothing exists.

Maintain concern for Dispel Magic spells, anti-magic areas, or attempts to incapacitate the Cleric.

Comment: Note that Spiritual Weapon doesn't require concentration, so incapacitating the cleric who cast it doesn't affect the weapon. Of course, it won't do anything without the caster taking a bonus action on their turn, but the weapon itself will remain.

Comment: Noted: incapacitating the cleric stops the threat posed by the Spiritual Weapon.